# Android: Application stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, eclipse-indigo

I am posting here a logcat file. How can I solve the `runtimeException` error. Logcat is showing this error:

> 03-03 03:12:30.716: E/AndroidRuntime(880): java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id
>   attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
>   Logcat:

```
03-03 03:46:30.607: D/AndroidRuntime(908): Shutting down VM
03-03 03:46:30.607: W/dalvikvm(908): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.FirstProject/com.example.FirstProject.City}:                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is     'android.R.id.list'
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:245)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:201)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at com.example.FirstProject.City.onCreate(City.java:23)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-03 03:46:30.657: E/AndroidRuntime(908):  ... 11 more
```

Code for class from where I am calling city.class:

```
package com.example.FirstProject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

//import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.widget.RadioButton;
//import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

public class FirstProjectActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
protected ListAdapter adapter;
Cursor cursor;
 protected String[] cities = {"Mumbai"};
 ListView lv ;
 ListView stations;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /* lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             int position, long id) {

             // When clicked, Open the Next Screen

            if(position==0)
            {

            }

            }
    });*/
}


public void myClickHandler(View view)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "button clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     /*setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
     ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
     ListView FirstProjectActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist1);
     FirstProjectActivity.setAdapter(adapter);*/
     Intent i=new Intent(this,City.class);
     i.setClass(this,City.class);
     startActivity(i);

}
/*public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      //  super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "yesss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, List.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("tn", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }*/
}
```

Code for the city.class to which I am calling:

```
package com.example.FirstProject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class City extends ListActivity{

protected ListAdapter adapter;
Cursor cursor;
protected String[] cities = {"Mumbai"};

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.screen1);
     ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cities);
     ListView FirstProjectActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist1);
     FirstProjectActivity.setAdapter(adapter);

 }

 public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(parent, view, position, id);
        Toast.makeText(this, "yesss",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, List.class);
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
        intent.putExtra("tn", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
 }
```

Comment: hey all the people,i have posted the code please help to resolve the problem.If you wants any more code like xml etc. please let me know.i will post it as soon as possible.thanx for giving your time.

Comment: -1 ... Search first, ask later ... This question is asked few times in a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListView FirstProjectActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist1);
```

change this to

```
  ListView FirstProjectActivity = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: the list which i am displaying is having name "mylist1",then how can i change mylist1 to list.i have tried but it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did not assign an ID to your `ListView`.  Maybe something else is going on, but its hard to tell without your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using ListActivity but forgot to add ListView (or haven't set it's id).
You need to add `<ListView android:id="@android:id/list" ...your properties..."/>` to layout

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the id as mylist1
use

```
android:id="android:id/list"
```

(in your xml)

then use in your java file

```
ListView lv=getListView();
```